# calling exec() in php

Tags: php, linux

Just migrated a website from a linux server without a cpanel to a server with a cpanel. My problem is when I hit start to start a process which executes a php file. It will not run the file. If I run the file from terminal everything works.

The code that calls the file.

```
if ($do === "start_service") {
     create_marker_file("$service_running_marker");
     system_bg("php $dir/$service_script");
     $message = "Started Service!";
     $running = true;
     $status = "Running";
}
```

The systembg is a function.

```
function system_bg($command) {
    exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid ' . $command . ' > /dev/null 2>&1  &"');
}
```

If i do `ps ax | grep service.php` in terminal is see this

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php-cgi /home/xsocial1/public_html/xsmp/service.php
```

When I run the file in terminal this is what i see when I run `ps ax | grep service.php`

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php service.php
```

I think my problem is I need the server to call a cli call and not a cgi call

Comment: Do you really have the `&` on a separate line like that?

Comment: No it is just the way it looks when I space over 8 spaces and paste the code. it is all on one line

Comment: You should paste the code and then use Ctl-k or the `{}` tool to mark it as code without wrapping.

Comment: I will do that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, you will need to figure out the CLI PHP path and use that to start the process. This is sadly not exactly standardised, but on a *nix machine you will usually have the right one by using `PHP_BINDIR .'/php'` (PHP_BINDIR being a PHP constant).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to check the webserver user has a privilegies to run the bash.